# Decimate removes faces, but not edges/vertices

Tags: modifiers

The model I'm working with is a very high-poly .ply file with over 5.6 million faces.

Obviously, that's far too high, so I imported it into Blender and attempted to reduce the face count using the Decimate modifier. Using the default Collapse tab, I set the ratio to
0.011%, bringing it down to about 65k faces.

When it finished loading, the number of edges and vertices remained constant, and instead of reshaping the model, it had simply deleted most of the faces. It's like punching most of the windows out of a glass dome. I tried ticking the "triangulate" option, but that did nothing. I then tried using the Un-Subdivide tab, but raising the Iterations count to just 1 froze Blender, and it never responded even after 15 minutes of waiting.

Comment: here's how to decimate then use merge by distance. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek2QfKYmlOo

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Did as the video said. The problem persists. It's still just punching holes in the model, and Merge by Distance doesn't fill them.

Comment: sounds like a bug. can you attach the file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Upp, actually, someone on reddit figured out the problem. Turns out none of the polys were connected in the first place. So the steps you listed were the correct ones; I just had to do them in reverse order.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the original .ply files had no connected polygons at all. They were all separated. To fix this, I used "Merge by Distance" to fuse them all together, and was then able to decimate just fine.